# (2003 Mercedes SLK230 Kompressor) Disarm the Alarm without Key Fob

Tags: mercedes-benz, alarm

I'm writing because my key fob stopped working, **this is distressing** because the last time my fob stopped working and I opened my door with my key alone, the alarm went off.

The entire time this last thing happened, my alarm was *loud as hell* and going off for about *40 minutes* because I had no way to disarm it or no knowledge to do so. I tried:

- Turning on the car (but it killed the engine because the alarm was still triggered, I assume)
- Using the dead fob.
- Sticking the key into the ignition and turning it to position 2

Nothing worked.

Anyways, It got towed to my preferred mechanic where the problem eventually stopped, we reconnected the battery and my mechanic said I could just stick my key in the trunk lock and turn it once or twice and that would disarm the alarm via key?

*is this true*? or am I just crazy.

I'm hoping it's true, because that'd solve the problem of me avoiding my car like the plague and hopefully being able to drive it again. I just don't want another 40 minutes of alarm hell going off in my neighborhood. >.>

Any people knowledge about German alarm systems in automobiles would be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: Great question!

Comment: Some cars do disable the alarm when you stick the key into a door/trunk lock and cycle it a few times. Can't guarantee it will work on the CLK. You could temporarily disconnect the siren to make it less distressing.

Comment: This should be documented in your owner's manual. You might also want to get in the habit of replacing the key in your fob on a regular basis (I know I do this annually, when I renew the registration).

Comment: As a follow up years later: There's really no solution here other than "lmao get it towed to your local dealership to handle this". This happened to me again a year after I posted this, too. The trunk solution never worked (for me). So basically just pray your neighbors won't mind the screeching death of your car that you can't get into without too much sound.